# Drag and Drop in Table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drag-and-drop

I need to achieve a drag and drop functionality inside a table with asp.net. My table will be generated dynamically, so number of rows and columns are dynamic. I want to move cell content (say cell has an image) to another column, this action may imply some restrictions on dragging the image to a particular column which will be handled from server side logic. How should I proceed with it.

**EDIT**

Also after drag and drop I want to save the layout and re load the saved layout next time the page is loaded.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following plugin, it provide all functionality like switching, cloning, etc.. built for tables.

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/783/Cool-Drag-and-Drop-table-content.html

or

http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

use [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/) to apply this functionality see [here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#default)